# How to send a hard-coded SAML2 response to AuthServices/Acs endpoint for testing

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

I need to integrate a SSO with our client who is using SAML2. I'm unfortunately using slightly older version (Kentor) of the library.

I have almost got the SSO flow working. The login button in my webpage correctly takes me to the clients sign-in page. On entering the username/password, the clients system authenticates and send back a valid response.

Unfortunately, the redirect from the client back to our auth end-point is failing with a "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied."

I want to hard code the saml response (which I can see in chrome debugging tools) and directly hit my auth localhost to debug what is going on. I tried using POSTMAN to no avail. Is there a way to do this?

This is the harcoded SAML i want to post to: http://localhost:11996/AuthServices/Acs

```
<samlp:Response Destination="http://localhost:11996/AuthServices/Acs"
ID="fbrVm-Lw67Z-Q7uihwClM5N_EXC" IssueInstant="2018-12-20T22:00:30.665Z" Version="2.0"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">xyz:abc:saml20:idp</saml:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#fbrVm-Lw67Z-Q7uihwClM5N_EXC">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>RYTG1QX8X/Jyu1BbnFbyeQvb0ZQjhfP7nbA7tdNLbfE=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
        EAIb9VfZ+ywNJGrMYfDGiYvgKo1UTiUB0yeDIZWsSvj4htvGPDTOwssyDdaFBSwB0B9/LjZB0GDD
        Bg3KR/ObpkW07t6Aoy0lSUt8pGJLvuXIcftsXGPeZTEt8ukNm66CZ7O2nGlalXBXvwBWHIUAJQ5j
        4tLkFJvGl/Ku0GF5madBgHrJq0023cjf5rb6+gksAOaSDawpbiXaRtQaluHyCkhgD8PuRoZRudCJ
        OW/1e70FZUb07EE5ZsN8cBXrERAfgECZc27GQ1l2v4ELlEdzNpnPJHugF+bgHowjeED/H0Hza4nl
        IriW+h8kAd2nyn5Kv6KnKG04DqoN+o0PsGGGaw==
    </ds:SignatureValue>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
<saml:Assertion ID="mS8eJV.gG4EXybyBs4uYWJsK2Es" IssueInstant="2018-12-20T22:00:32.250Z"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml:Issuer>xyz:abc:saml20:idp</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
        <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">10035094</saml:NameID>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T22:05:32.250Z"
            Recipient="https://mvauth-staging.mvtransit.com/AuthServices/Acs"/></saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-20T21:55:32.250Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T22:05:32.250Z">
        <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:Audience>xyz:abc:saml20:sp</saml:Audience>
        </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-20T22:00:30.665Z"
        SessionIndex="mS8eJV.gG4EXybyBs4uYWJsK2Es">
        <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
        </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Attribute Name="firstname"
            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">John</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="adLogon" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">jsmith</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="lastname" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Smith</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="upi" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">20181220</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

Answer (score 1):

A hard coded response is hard to do, because it will

1. not be valid (a response contains time restrictions) and
2. trigger the replay detection.

So for testing, I created the stubidp available at https://stubidp.sustainsys.com. You can configure it by creating an own tenant and editing the json settings file, to provide a response that contains the same attributes as you list in your sample. The optional stuff such as NameFormat will not be in there - but as the library ignores it there's no point in having it for testing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I believe I have made some progress. I enabled logging in Kentor.AuthServices and realized some of my settings in web.config was wrong. 
I was consitently getting "Received unsolicited Saml Response" error so I changed "allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse" to false and setup a "returnUrl". 
Now, I get "Successfully processed SAML response Ejx3U2coHBmIhjtYikGZr-HUf_u and authenticated 10035094".

Comment: This is how my config looks: `code`<kentor.authServices entityId="https://staging.abc.com/MVSAMLServiceProvider" returnUrl="https://dfjliyd.ngrok.io/api/Account/UnsolicitedExternalLogin">
 <identityProviders>      
   <add entityId="xyz:abc:saml20:idp"
     metadataLocation="~/Providers/SAML2/Metadata/xyz.xml"
     allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"
     disableOutboundLogoutRequests="false"
     binding="HttpRedirect">
   </add>
 </identityProviders>
</kentor.authServices>

Comment: Unfortunately, at my returnUrl (api/Account/UnsolicitedExternalLogin which is a GET), User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false and I'm not getting any claims back.
Next, I tried using one of your sugestions and did this:
  app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            });
What I realized is that the "Set-Cookie" is never returned in the header. Please help?

Comment: Logs should contain the error. But I think the error is that your entity Id is not a valid absolute Uri. add http(s) in front of "staging.abc.com..."

Comment: There is a h.t.t.p.s which was automatically removed when I posted the comment. Two things, 1. that absolute url which is set for entityid returns a 404, it this an issue?

Comment: 2. In my logs, i see this: ERROR 2018-12-28 10:50:33,423 2820637ms emv-authService-logger LoadMetadata       - Metadata loading failed from https://staging.xyz.com/Federation
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)
   at Kentor.AuthServices.Metadata.MetadataLoader.Load(String metadataLocation)
   at Kentor.AuthServices.Metadata.MetadataLoader.LoadFederation(String metadataLocation)
   at Kentor.AuthServices.Federation.LoadMetadata()

Comment: https:/staging.xyz.com/Federation is what i have setup for : <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="https:/staging.xyz.com/Federation" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>

Comment: Anders, I'm Completely stuck. logs have no errors:

MoveNext           - Received unsolicited Saml Response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M which is allowed for idp abc:xyz:saml20:idp
MoveNext           - Signature validation passed for Saml Response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M
MoveNext           - Extracted SAML assertion oN4v.k9x2GE7s5S8OdeNWS.93j9
MoveNext           - Validated conditions for SAML2 Response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M
ProcessResponse    - Successfully processed SAML response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M and authenticated 10035094

Comment: Please don't add further information in the comments. A question should be complete without requiring comments. Plus,  code or error messages posted in comments is completely unreadable. Edit your question and add everything to it, please.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll create a new question as this question is answered!